# Extract all data with same key from the dictionary into another array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just want to know a easy way to extract all data with same key `"Cat"` from the dictionary into another array.

From the below dictionary..
All data with key `"Cat: Book"` should be in a separate array and key `"Cat: pen"` in another.
This dictionary is dynamic and more different `"Cat"` values can come in.

```
category= [{'Cat':'Book','Item':'LongBook','Qty':'25'}, 
           {'Cat':'Book','Item':'Diary','Qty':'20'}, 
           {'Cat':'Pen','Item':'BallPoint','Qty':'30'}]
```

Comment: I think he means that he wants to get all these dictionaries, get dicts with the same 'Cat:*' and merge them ?

Comment: jamylak, i want to extract all the data from the dictionary based on key 'Cat', like all the data for Key 'Cat:book' in one array and all data for Key 'Cat:pen' in another.

Comment: Add example output to your questions so it is more clear for everybody and you will be less likely to get downvoted :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite difficult to understand what do you really need. Anyway try to take a look at the following code that [uses defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict):

```
category= [{'Cat':'Book','Item':'LongBook','Qty':'25'}, 
           {'Cat':'Book','Item':'Diary','Qty':'20'}, 
           {'Cat':'Pen','Item':'BallPoint','Qty':'30'}]

from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(list)

for row in category:
    output['Cat' + ':' + row['Cat']].append(row)

print output.values()

>>>[[{'Item': 'BallPoint', 'Qty': '30', 'Cat': 'Pen'}], [{'Item': 'LongBook', 'Qty': '25', 'Cat': 'Book'}, {'Item': 'Diary', 'Qty': '20', 'Cat': 'Book'}]]
```

Or better [use groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby):

```
category= [{'Cat':'Book','Item':'LongBook','Qty':'25'}, 
           {'Cat':'Book','Item':'Diary','Qty':'20'}, 
           {'Cat':'Pen','Item':'BallPoint','Qty':'30'}]

from itertools import groupby

for key, vals in groupby(category, lambda x: x['Cat']):
    print key, list(vals)

>>>Book [{'Item': 'LongBook', 'Qty': '25', 'Cat': 'Book'}, {'Item': 'Diary', 'Qty': '20', 'Cat': 'Book'}]
>>>Pen [{'Item': 'BallPoint', 'Qty': '30', 'Cat': 'Pen'}]
```